# Saving output of a recursive function as a list

Tags: r, recursion

I'd like to save the output of my recursive function as a list.

```
> (getNames(74, foo))
[1] "Excavata"
[1] "Excavata"
[1] "Excavata"
[1] "Excavata"
[1] "Stramenopiles"
[1] "Stramenopiles"
[1] "Stramenopiles"
[1] "Excavata"
[1] "Excavata"
[1] "Metazoa"
```

How do I go about doing this? Maybe this is simpler than I think but I've been stuck for a couple of days!

I don't think the code here matters: the general idea of my question regards saving the output of a recursive function (such as towers of hanoi) as a data type such as a list or a data.frame.

Comment: Exact code may not matter, but it's always easier to answer a question that provides a reproducible example.

Comment: Please make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)! This will be hard to answer without knowing what your `recursive` function does, and how it does it.

Comment: Not clear to me what you want. Can you give an example function and inputs and the desired output of this "convert to list" operation you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really think the exact code doesn't matter:

```
recursive_add <- function(x, res_list=NULL) {
  if (is.null(res_list)) {
    res_list <- list()
  }
  if (x == 26) {
    return(res_list)
  }
  res_list[[x]] <- letters[x]
  res_list <- recursive_add(x + 1, res_list)
  return(res_list)
}
recursive_add(1)
```

The default `NULL` argument allows you to create a new list the first time, but then pass the existing list down to the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Without code to see I'm not sure as to whether it would be useful, but have you considered using rapply? [rapply help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/rapply.html) its a recursive version of lapply and lapply returns lists as output.